# how to set textview background auto fit when device font increase or decrease

Tags: android

textview.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_badge"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/baseline_grid_3x"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/item_padding"
        android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
        android:padding="@dimen/baseline_grid_0.5x" tools:text="9"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="@dimen/app_text_size_small"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
```

red_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
```

this is my code from which

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="oval">

  <solid android:color="@color/colorRed" />

  <stroke
     android:width="0dp"
     android:color="@color/colorRed" />

  <size
     android:width="20dp"
     android:height="20dp"" />

</shape>
```

I am trying to display textview with circular with text it works fine when device font size less when device font size large then textview background become circle to oval when I try to change size 20dp to 60dp then in becomes circle please suggest me how to fix it how to keep circle background of textview when we increase font size

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ConstraintLayout` to make `TextView` width always equals `TextView` height => it will make `TextView` background always circle

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="AAAAAAAAAAAA"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: OK thanx wait let me check and will let youknow